# Object Animator throws Runtime Exception though everything looks okay to me. Please point out what is causing this

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception, objectanimator

It was running okay before adding and object animator to animate an ImageView. But after creating an animation, it started throwing Runtime Exceptions. I can not figure out what is the problem though I know the animator is causing it, because if I remove the codes of animator initialisation, it works fine. Please anyone help me solving this. Thanks!
This is the stack of the Runtime Exception:

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2304    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2354 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 150    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1244  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5191    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 795  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 562 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

This is my code:

```
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Startup extends Activity {
    private boolean itIsMultiplayerCard = false;
    private float x, y;
    private int screenWidth, screenHeight, initX, finX;
    private Animation goDown, goUp;
    private ObjectAnimator centerSlider;
    private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
    private FrameLayout startUpFrameLayout;
    private ImageView backImageView, playNowImageView, multiplayerImageView,         optionsImageView, exitImageView;

    private OnClickListener backImageListener = new OnClickListener()   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener playNowListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

    private OnClickListener multiplayerListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itIsMultiplayerCard = true;
            optionsImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
            exitImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
            multiplayerImageView.setOnClickListener(backListener);
            multiplayerImageView.startAnimation(goDown);
            multiplayerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            multiplayerImageView.bringToFront();
            multiplayerImageView.startAnimation(goUp);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener optionsListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            itIsMultiplayerCard = false;
            multiplayerImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
            exitImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
            optionsImageView.setOnClickListener(backListener);
            optionsImageView.startAnimation(goDown);
            optionsImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
            optionsImageView.bringToFront();
            optionsImageView.startAnimation(goUp);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener exitListener = new OnClickListener()    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener backListener = new OnClickListener()    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(itIsMultiplayerCard) {
                optionsImageView.setOnClickListener(optionsListener);
                multiplayerImageView.setOnClickListener(multiplayerListener);
                multiplayerImageView.startAnimation(goDown);
                multiplayerImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.mul_u);
                playNowImageView.bringToFront();
                backImageView.bringToFront();
                multiplayerImageView.startAnimation(goUp);
            } else  {
                multiplayerImageView.setOnClickListener(multiplayerListener);
                optionsImageView.setOnClickListener(optionsListener);
                optionsImageView.startAnimation(goDown);
                optionsImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.op_u);
                multiplayerImageView.bringToFront();
                playNowImageView.bringToFront();
                backImageView.bringToFront();
                optionsImageView.startAnimation(goUp);
            }
            itIsMultiplayerCard = false;
            exitImageView.setOnClickListener(exitListener);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startup);

        displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        initX = backImageView.getWidth();
        finX = ((screenWidth / 2) - (235 / 2));
        goUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_up);
        goDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_down);
        startUpFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.startUpFrameLayout);
        backImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backImageView);
        playNowImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playNowImageView);
        multiplayerImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.multiplayerImageView);
        optionsImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.optionsImageView);
        exitImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.exitImageView);
        centerSlider = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(backImageView, "TranslationX", -117, 117);

        backImageView.setOnClickListener(backImageListener);
        playNowImageView.setOnClickListener(playNowListener);
        multiplayerImageView.setOnClickListener(multiplayerListener);
        optionsImageView.setOnClickListener(optionsListener);
        exitImageView.setOnClickListener(exitListener);
        playNowImageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
        multiplayerImageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
        optionsImageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
        exitImageView.setAlpha(0.0f);
        centerSlider.setDuration(300);
        centerSlider.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to answer it. Found the problem. It was a silly mistake by me.
I wrote `initX = backImageView.getWidth();` before initializing the `backImageView()` which caused the exception. It is not caused by the animator.